# Regarding a certain definition of the auxiliary "have"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/have) defines *have* in the 4th sub-entry under the 2nd entry as:

> **2.4**  [*with object and complement*] Cause to be in a particular state or condition.

What would be a synonym that has an akin definition?

Here are some examples where the synonym could be used:

> I **had** the TV on with the sound turned down.
>
> We cannot chastise her for what she does, because, ultimately, he **had** us fooled as well.

Comment: This isn't an auxiliary use of *have* because the correct negation needs *do*: "I **did**n't have the tv on..."

Comment: @Laurel *The TV had volume* versus *the TV hadn't [any] volume.* Although the negated version is uncommon, it's not wrong.

Comment: @JasonBassford That's not the same sense of the verb that OP is talking about because it doesn't have an object and complement. Do you really think that "I hadn't the tv on", "had I the tv on?", "he hadn't us fooled", and "had he us fooled?" sound right? (My dialect treats possessive *have* as nonauxiliary, and I've been using Google/BNC to gauge what other dialects say, but I couldn't find any examples of this sense of *have* used an auxiliary.)

Comment: @Laurel Both *Had I the TV on?* and *Hadn't I the TV on?* are grammatical—and I've occasionally heard that construction in actual use. (Although, as I say, it's not common. It sounds more old fashioned than modern.)

Comment: Is there any difference between "He had us fooled" and "He fooled us"?

Comment: "Had" is not an auxiliary verb here. The verb "have" is an auxiliary in the perfect tense but elsewhere it's generally treated as a lexical verb. Lexical "have" requires do-support in negation "He doesn't have any money", while auxiliary "have" does not, as in "He hasn't any money".

Comment: @Norbert There's no difference in meaning, though they are different constructions, of course.